# Why is my else if statement not working in observeEvent?

Tags: r, shiny

The code is as below as an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

df <- data.frame(
    "obs" = 1:26,
    "letters" = LETTERS
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
            box(
                textInput("txt", "", value = ""),
                actionButton("btn1", "btn1"),
                actionButton("btn2", "btn2")
            ),
            box(
                dataTableOutput("tbl")
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    rndDF <-
        reactiveVal(data.frame())
    
    observeEvent(input$btn1 | input$btn2, {
        updateTextInput(session, "txt", value = sample(df$letters, 1))
        if(input$btn1){
            dt <- df %>%
                filter(letters == input$txt) %>% 
                mutate(status = "ok")
            rndDF(rbind(rndDF(), dt))
        } else if (input$btn2){
            dt <- df %>%
                filter(letters == input$txt) %>% 
                mutate(status = "---")
            rndDF(rbind(rndDF(), dt))
        }
    })
    
    output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
        rndDF()
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The above code saves the information given by the user as a table. 'status' column will change according to user click on first or second button. The first one is working but second one is not. It also writes 'ok' to the table for the second button. What exactly am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: can you try `paste0(input$btn1,input$btn2)` as the first argument of `observeEvent`

Comment: that's because `input$btn1` returns the number of times the `btn1` was clicked, not TRUE or FALSE

Comment: @SametSökel I get the same result.

Comment: @AlexandreLéonard When I click the second button first I get what I want. What to do to make it work?

Comment: You could create two observeEvents

Comment: It works but I didn't want to do that :) Thanks @AlexandreLéonard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it behaves like this is already explained by @Alexandre Léonard . When the button is clicked you don't get `TRUE`/`FALSE` values but a number. Now to differentiate the two clicks you can have two `observeEvent`.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        textInput("txt", "", value = ""),
        actionButton("btn1", "btn1"),
        actionButton("btn2", "btn2")
      ),
      box(
        dataTableOutput("tbl")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rndDF <-
    reactiveVal(data.frame())
  
  observeEvent(input$btn1, {
    updateTextInput(session, "txt", value = sample(df$letters, 1))
    dt <- df %>%
      filter(letters == input$txt) %>% 
      mutate(status = "ok")
    rndDF(rbind(rndDF(), dt))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn2, {
    updateTextInput(session, "txt", value = sample(df$letters, 1))
    dt <- df %>%
      filter(letters == input$txt) %>% 
      mutate(status = "ok")
    rndDF(rbind(rndDF(), dt))
  })
  
  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    rndDF()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You could further extract the piece of code inside your two observée vent into a function which would take a status as parameter. Less code duplicate